# start_request on scrpy.spyder does not seem to work fine

Tags: python, scrapy

I hope you can give me some hints with my problem here.

I'm tryng to obtain an ordered data from a txt source. The code works fine till I print the data from the txt source, so it reads it. But onces I start a loop, reading each line from the txt file spydering it, and I "print(origdato)" to check if its working fine, but it does not.

Maybe is the loop, maybe is the request from spyder, I really dont know.

Could you please help me?

Here the code:

```py
    # packages
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    import json 
    import datetime
    
    # scraper class 
    class myfile(scrapy.Spider):
        # scraper name
        name= 'whatever'
        
        base_url = 'https://www.whatever.com/'
    
        headers =  {'...'
          }  
        
        custom_settings =  {
            'CONCURRENT_REQUEST_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
            'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        }
            
        current_page = 2
    
        origdatos= []
    
        
        def __init__(self):
         
            content = ''
    
          with open('origdatos.txt', 'r') as f:
                for line in f.read():
                    content += line
    
            # parse content
            self.origdatos= content.split('\n')
           # print(self.origdatos) // Till heree works fine 
    
           # crawler
            def start_requests(self):
                self.current_page = 2
    
                # loop over datos
                for origdato in self.origdatos:
                 print(origdato) #In this print Python does not show me data, so it appears the loop does not work properly, maybe
                 
          #driver
        if __name__ == '__main__':
        # run scraper
        process = CrawlerProcess()
        process.crawl(myfile)
        process.start()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your code is all over the place, is that how you have formatted it in your original file as well?

Comment: No, sorry I had some issues to copy and paste the code in SO, sorry, Im new posting here.Thanks for your help. I aproved your correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a formatting issue with your code. If it is formatted as displayed in your question that is. Try unindenting the `start_requests`method in your code and see if it fixes the problem.

The following should work as well:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class myfile(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'whatever'

    def __init__(self):
        with open('origdatos.txt', 'r') as f:
            self.origdatos = f.readlines()

    def start_requests(self):
        for origdato in self.origdatos:
            print(origdato)
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(myfile)
    process.start()
```

However, this will still produce an error at the end of execution, because `start_requests` is supposed to return an iterable.

Comment: Oh it works perfect, I'm quite new on python I didnt know the importance of the indenting here. It works putting order on my code. Thanks a lot¡ I will continue applying your advice. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, indentation is quite important in Python. It basically replaces the curly braces ({}) used in other programming languages. Meaning if you indented `start_requests` to be inside `__init__` it would only have been available inside `__init__` and therefore not directly be accessible to objects of the class `myfile`.

Comment: Yes, I had other issue that I was trying to solve and finally works with your advice too. So Thanks again, it was very helpful.